# java.io.UncheckedIOException / java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException mention different charsets when reading files in a directory

Tags: java, file, character-encoding, nio, java-io

I'm getting different variations of the same `java.io.UncheckedIOException` when running a test in an IDE or in the terminal:

**In IDE:**

```
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Failed to read C:\code\STS\daily-cash-report\target\test-classes\zipTmp\October 3 Files content with UTF-8 charset
    at org.assertj.core.api.AbstractFileAssert.readFile(AbstractFileAssert.java:1436)
    at org.assertj.core.api.AbstractFileAssert.internalContent(AbstractFileAssert.java:1428)
    at org.assertj.core.api.AbstractFileAssert.content(AbstractFileAssert.java:1350)
    at com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.AchFileUtilsTest.lambda$0(AchFileUtilsTest.java:313)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at com.abc.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.AchFileUtilsTest.processZippedFiles(AchFileUtilsTest.java:311)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\code\STS\daily-cash-report\target\test-classes\zipTmp\October 3 Files
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
```

**In Maven:**

```
[ERROR] Errors:                                                                                                                     
[ERROR]   AchFileUtilsTest.processZippedFiles:311->lambda$processZippedFiles$0:313 � UncheckedIO Failed to read C:\code\STS\daily-ca
sh-report\target\test-classes\zipTmp\October 3 Files content with windows-1252 charset                                              
[INFO]
```

As seen from the above, the same exception referes to **UTF-8** charset in IDE and to the **windows-1252** one in Maven.

Here's the culprit test:

```
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    public void processZippedFiles() {

        String zipFileLocation = "/october3/October 3 Files.zip";
        File zipFileToUnmarshall = new ClassPathResource(zipFileLocation).getFile();

        File tmpContainer = new File(new ClassPathResource(".").getFile().getPath() + "/zipTmp");

        if (FileUtils.unzip(zipFileToUnmarshall, tmpContainer)) {

            Files.list(tmpContainer.toPath()).forEach(p -> {
                File originalFile = p.toFile();
                assertThat(originalFile).content().contains(ASCII_SUB_CHAR);
                String normalizedOriginalFileName = com.pru.globalpayments.feeds.downstream.dailycashreport.FileUtils
                        .normalize(originalFile);

                String fixedFileName = normalizedOriginalFileName + FXD;

                NormalizedResult normalized = null;
                try {
                    // both content- and name-wise
                    normalized = cut.normalize(originalFile, fixedFileName);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 

                File fullyNormalizedOriginalFileToUnmarshal = normalized.getFile();

                int validLines = normalized.getNumberOfValidLines();

                assertThat(fullyNormalizedOriginalFileToUnmarshal).content().doesNotContain(ASCII_SUB_CHAR);

                String maskedFileName = fullyNormalizedOriginalFileToUnmarshal.getAbsolutePath() + MSK;

                File maskedFile = null;
                try {
                    maskedFile = cut.maskSensitiveData(fullyNormalizedOriginalFileToUnmarshal, maskedFileName);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                assertThat(maskedFile).isNotEmpty();
                long maskedNumberOfLines = 0L;
                try {
                    maskedNumberOfLines = countLines(maskedFile);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                assertThat(maskedNumberOfLines).isEqualTo(validLines);
            });
            // FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(tmpContainer);
        }

    }
```

This is how the directory is populated with the files processed by the above test:

```
    /**
     * Utility to unzip contents of a supplied zip file into the supplied destination folder
     * 
     * @param zipToUnzip
     * @param destinationFolder
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static boolean unzip(File zipToUnzip, File destinationFolder) throws Exception {

        boolean result;
        
        FileSystemUtils.deleteRecursively(destinationFolder);

        try (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(zipToUnzip);) {
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> enumEntries = zipFile.entries();
            while (enumEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
                ZipEntry entry = (ZipEntry) enumEntries.nextElement();
                File destFile = new File(destinationFolder, entry.getName());
                if (!destFile.exists()) {
                    destFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                }
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    continue;
                }
                try (InputStream is = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destFile)) {
                    while (is.available() > 0) {
                        fos.write(is.read());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        result = true;
        return result;
    }
```

What could be missing here?
Why are the charsets used different depending on execution environment?
There is also the following caused by stanza in the first stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\code\STS\daily-cash-report\target\test-classes\zipTmp\October 3 Files
```

Could that be a culprit?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to read a directory as a file.

Comment: @user207421 `FileUtils.unzip(zipFileToUnmarshall, tmpContainer)` creates extracts 18 files into that `tmpContainer`.  However, `Files.list(tmpContainer.toPath()).forEash(p->{System.out.println(p);});` displays only the root folder, instead of those 18 files.  Weird.